# OneToOne related other model field converted to boolean field check box in form to show or hide model fields doesn’t work

Tags: django

**I have these two django blog models in models.py**
`

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # the same field in comment model for multi-inheritance (post_id)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, editable=False) # add unique=True in slug (never repeat)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, default='')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, help_text="Select a tag for this post", related_name='post_tags')
    snippet = models.OneToOneField(Snippet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_snippets')
    ...
```

and i have forms to add new post as follows

```
class PostModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "Post #%s) %s" % (obj.id, obj.title)
class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = PostModelChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.all())
    class Meta:      
        model = Snippet
        fields = '__all__'

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        #fields = '__all__'
        #fields = ['title', 'tag', 'maintainer', 'post_img', 'content', 'snippet', 'genre', 'language', 'video', 'post_type', 'urls', 'views', 'status' ]
        labels = {'snippet': _('Add Code'),}
        exclude = ('creator', 'slug',)
        widgets = {
            'snippet': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'type': 'checkbox', 'class': 'checkbox', 'id': 'post-snippet'})
        }
    def clean(self):
        snippet = self.cleaned_data.get('snippet')
        if snippet:
            self.fields_required(snippet.title, snippet.code, snippet.title, snippet.linenos, snippet.language, snippet.style, snippet.highlighted) # ['title', 'code', 'linenos', ....]
        else:
            self.cleaned_data['snippet'] = False
        return self.cleaned_data
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Post.objects.filter(snippet=True)
```

and views logic to render template

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        snippet = post_form.cleaned_data['snippet']
        if snippet:
            #snpt = modelformset_factory(Snippet, fields=('title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style', 'highlighted'))
            snpt = Snippet.objects.create(post = request.post, snippet_id = request.post.id)
            snippet_form = SnippetForm(request.POST, instance=snpt)
        if post_form.is_valid() and snippet_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            snpt = snippet_form.save(commit=False)
            post.creator = request.user
            post.snippet = snpt
            post.slug = slugify(post_form.cleaned_data['title'])
            post.save() and snpt.save()
            obj = post_form.instance
            alert = True
            return redirect('blog:post_list')
            #return render(request, "add_post.html",{'obj':obj, 'alert':alert})
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('blog/post_list/success/')
    else:
        post_form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html', {'form': post_form})
```

`
**Now i can’t get the snippet fields in my template when i tick the check box in the template**

**Here is the form**

```
<form method='POST' class="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        {{ form.non_field_errors }} {% csrf_token %} {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="apply">
                            {% if field.errors %}
                            <ol>
                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ol>
                            {% endif %} {% if field.help_text %}
                            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %} {% bootstrap_form form %}
                        <button class="boxed-btn3 w-100" type="submit">Post</button>
                    </form>
```

**what’s wrong in this logic why the snippet form doesn’t show up in the template and how to get it live immediately when i check the boolean field add code (snippet) in the page form
please help me**

[image]

**i tried to get all the Snippet model fields into add post model form to show all fields in one form
but can't get the fields while i have all post model fields rendered well but when i checked the
check box field snippet that has been converted into boolean in post form , nothing happens**

Comment: You need to use javascript.

Comment: You do know you can add your own fields to a `ModelForm` / `Form` and don't need to repurpose an existing model field for that? Also you should create an extra form for the snippet and use some JavaScript to show it conditionally as @SunderamDubey mentions